# GraphTypeFromType gets NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I'm getting this error using dotnet's bindings for Graphql, what may it be the cause?

> GraphQL.ExecutionError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>            at System.Object.GetType()
>            at GraphQL.Types.TypeExtensions.GraphTypeFromType(IType type, ISchema schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that if the query sent to be executed contains unknown types `GraphTypeFromType` will fail with that exception.

This is actually a bug in GraphQL.NET which is fixed [by this commit](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/commit/eefc942b0573fbb0149b016085a3ca4567e9f195).